# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::createToken(),

Tags: laravel-passport

I have API Laravel5 project using laravel passport & oauth.How to fix the above error.

I can't create API Tocken..

```
public function login(){
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you haven't added `use HasApiTokens` in User model.

Refer configuration instructions on: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport